# Why did Dean and Cindy separate?

Tags: plot-explanation, blue-valentine

What was the reason for Dean and Cindy's marriage to fall apart in *Blue Valentine*? Seems like Dean was ready to change his ways. Why didn't Cindy give him a chance?

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, Cindy's life is not going as she expected: she was studying medicine and then got pregnant; she tried abortion, but had to stop halfaway, so now she is a nurse.

At the beginning Dean's attitude made her fell safe, then she started to feel suffocated by his lack of initiative: he is always saying something like

> You tell me what to do, and I do it!

this is irritating in every person, even more in a husband: he should cooperate not put all their relationship on her shoulder; in the long run this killed her respect for him and their relationship.

I would say he is kind of childish.

From the [Rotten Tomato analysis](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/blue_valentine/):

> A complex portrait of a contemporary American marriage, "Blue
>   Valentine" tells the story of Dean and Cindy, a couple who have been
>   together for several years but who are at an impasse in their
>   relationship. While Cindy has blossomed into a woman with
>   opportunities and options, David is still the same person he was when
>   they met, and he is unable to accept either Cindy's growth or his lack
>   of it.

Comment: That is a point. But the fact that Dean accepted their child even after knowing it might not be his. And also that he truly loves their daughter. I feel a bit disappointed for him. But hey it is just a story. Thanks for replying.